# Program to search for character and word irregularities in text documents

Tags: text, ms-word, ocr

Is there a program that can scan for irregularities in text documents and fix them?.  For example, an OCR document might have words that are broken up, such as w o  rd s  no t  toget he r , or too many spaces between words or extra line breaks.  I have run across programs that can fix extra spaces or linebreaks, but I have not seen any that fix more complicated problems like broken up words.  Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, software library, book, tutorial, or other off-site resource are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what scans as "w o r d" might as easily scan as "w o r k" or "w o r o".  So, removing the spaces won't really help.  MSWORD will accept regex terms in its "find" feature to show you all instances of "space-letter-space-letter-space" to find broken words.

Here is the MS Word regex documentation.  I t  i s  u p  t o  y o u   if you want to use the replace feature:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f